# Git revert certain parts of large commit

Tags: git, github

I have a rails app where I made some migrations about 20 commits ago and then ultimately didnt need the tables created. I pushed the changes up to github so the schema and migrations are in my git history but no one has cloned or used my branch. I was wondering if there was a way I could git revert back to that commit and just removed the migration aspect of the commit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You first have to "revert" those commit you don't want, than push again to GitHub to remove from your online history.

Let's see how:

**STEP 1**

To revert to some commit, you can run `git rebase` in any of the following way.

a) if you know the SHA1 of the commit you want to revert to (note the "^" at the end):

```
git rebase -i SHA1^
```

or,

b) if you know it was 20 commits ago:

```
git rebase -i HEAD~21
```

Doing that, Git will open vim.

**STEP2**

Now you'll see the list of your commit with `short SHA-1` and commit message.
Delete all the ones you no more want (blank lines and comments - starting with "#" - are ignored) with `dd` for each line, or `d20d` if you want to delete 20 lines starting from the one you are on. Save and Exit (with `:wq`). Git will remove all the commits you just removed.

**IMPORTANT**: if saved file is empty or only has blank lines and/or comments, Git aborts the operation.

**STEP 3**

Update your GitHub repository with those changes. To do that you have to force the push:

```
git push --force origin/master
```

I'm supposing you tracked GitHub repository as origin and you're working on your master branch.
Otherwise replace those with your configuration.

**END**
You removed those unwanted commits both from your local and from GitHub.

Answer (score 0):

I would run a rebase

```
git rebase -i <commit>^
```

then change the `pick` to `edit`

Comment: thanks, would you know the syntax for editing a specific commit?

Comment: @BC00 I dont understand the question. After you change pick to edit, it will allow you to edit and re-commit.

Comment: @BC00 have you run the command? When you do it opens your editor with the commit list...

Comment: its taking me to vim which i dont know, if i run git revert and then edit and re-commit, does that just create a new commit? it doesnt actually edit or associate the revert to the commit i made previously?

Comment: You can change the editor to one you are able to use. Simply modify or add this line in your `.gitconfig` in your home directory:  
`[core]`  
`editor = kate`

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution: 
Like Steven said, the interactive rebase is a good to go.

`$ git rebase -i [the_commit_preceding_your_problematic_commit]`

Launching this command, you'll be prompted into your editor with a menu in which you'll see all the commits starting from the problematic commit (at the top).
Each commit is preceded by the pick keyword.

To edit a commit, you've got to replace pick by **edit** or **e**.
Saving and leaving the editor, you 'll be in a detached HEAD state at the commit you labeled with edit. (As if you time travelled until the day of that commit)
Now you have to reset the commit.

`$ git reset HEAD^`

ie you go one step behind. You 'll see all the files of your commit in your stagging area but not yet in the index.

`$ git status`

Now you can remove the files you want, add the other one and commit.
Your commit will be now like you want.

Remenber you're still in a detached HEAD state. To tell git everything is OK, you have to type:

`$ git rebase --continue`

And git take you back to the real last commit you've made.
**BUT**, you rewrote all the history of your git branch.

In order to push your modification you'll have to specify --force option of the push command.

**Note**: While rebasing, if something goes wrong, do a:

`$ git rebase --abort`